# Check if files exists without too much garbage

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection

I'm trying to do the following: I've a database filled with file names located under a directory. This directory is changing constantly (downloaded files are being added and removed). My application is supposed to scan this directory for the first time and add the files into the database. The second time the application will run, it needs to check if the filenames in the database are still available in the directory.

For the check I use the following pseudo code:

```
get the filename from the database
check if exists (file f = new File(filename))
                 if (f.exists()){
                     mark as existing;
                  } else {
                    mark is as deleted
                  }

if it does, then mark it as existing, else mark it as removed (later will clean the database up)
```

The question is: How can I check all the files on the database if they exists without producing much garbage? Files can be more than 1000. Running the loop with "new File(...)" more than 1000 times will cause too much garbage.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `File()` object is really tiny. It has **only path string** in it and reference to the FileSystem object. It just look like a wasting resources, but it's not.

Think about `File` object as a path String with few helper methods to deal with file paths.
It has nothing to do with file descriptor or other heavy resources.

**Never do optimization before profiling.** You will end up with non optimal difficult to maintain code.

Comment: That is correct--File does not really open the file, but it is the wrong way of going about the problem.

Comment: @Michał Šrajer. Thanks for the answer. I've made a simple application and looked like the File Object was about 100 bytes for a normal file name. That might not be the bottleneck of my application then. Will profile further. +1

Answer (score 4):

> Files can be more than 1000. Running the loop with "new File(...)"
>   more than 1000 times will cause too much garbage.

Really?  Have you tested this?  I can't see this being a significant concern under modern systems.  (What are you most worried about?  The JVM garbage collection?)

Otherwise, get the current directory, then call `.list()` or `.listFiles()`, load into a `Set` for performance (a `HashSet` would probably do nicely), then just query against the Set.  (You'll still be creating Strings and entries within the Set that could be a similar GC concern.)  The potential problem here is that you're now loading a potentially "large" number of elements into memory within the JVM - rather than checking on-demand as you read each row out of the database.

I'd stick with the code that you have outlined.  +1 for Michal's answer - please review for additional details as to why doing this should be of no concern.

Comment: Well, I've profiled the application and the memory went high while scanning. That is why I thought that the File creation will cause this issue. Now it it clear that it is just a sting and it does nothing with the file itself. Thanks for the answer. +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Do it the other way--you add a set of rows to a database table.  You then scan the directory the files are in and just get a list of filenames and compare that list to a 'select names from filesTable'  type of query.

Comment: That is also a possibility but don't know what impact will it have on performance. Thanks anyways for commenting.